# Not able to boot to already installed Windows and Ubuntu in Hard drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am facing problems with OS booting of my laptop. I had a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1. I generally work in Ubuntu and one day when I started my system Ubuntu wasn't booting up. It showed error that some file has been deleted, I wasn't able to understand that because I am a newbie in linux, so after that I booted Windows and then made a partition in hard drive and installed ubuntu again in it. After the installation was successful, I restarted the system, but my system directly booted up to new Ubuntu. There was no initial GRUB screen where I could choose which OS to boot up. I started working in the Ubuntu again and I checked that my Windows and previous Ubuntu were still installed in hard drive but I didn't knew how to access those. Once again I thought I should try to install the windows again. I had the iso file of Windows 8.1. I burned it on USB stick through Ubuntu Terminal by using the command

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=windows8.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

and I tried to install the windows through it but system didn't recognized the boot device. I removed the USB stick and restarted the system but now newly installed Ubuntu was also not booting up! Now there is a screen saying no internal drive found, Press F1 to reboot and two other options. I have checked by trying the ubuntu without installing, from USB stick in which I had iso file of Ubuntu burned that all the 3 operating system are present in my hard drive but nothing is booting up. Is there any way I can recover my windows and Ubuntu? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my advice.  Please boot your computer to [boot repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).  Please do not try to install boot repair onto your ubuntu installation or you may make matters worse.  I hear it works for others but never for me, so I must advise you not to try doing it that way.

When prompted to copy down a code, please to that so that you can recover and post the results here for further analysis should you be unsuccessful.  I'm no expert at determining those results, but I learn a little more each time, and several times, I've spotted the problem.

Comment: I had tried boot repair before and it showed the error- I tried boot repair onto my Ubuntu installation but it showed this error. ' GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again. '

Comment: I did this following the second option provided in this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You want me to try the first option. Right?